# Analytics Embed API Multi Account

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm working with this api but I have a problem.

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api

My web application is running fine with my user and client id, but I would like to give access to my partners but they can't access with my clientid.

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
});
```

Can I have a multi account application using this api? 
I can't create more users in Google Developer Console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They *can* access your app with your client ID. What they may not have access to is your Google Analytics accounts.

The Embed API allows a user to log in and view dashboards/reports for GA data from the **accounts to which they have access**. So if you want your partners to be able to see what you're seeing, you'll have to add them to your GA account.